# How do I change a url value based on a cell value in excel 2013 VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new to programming and coding world and have come across a snag in my VBA coding. I need to change a value in a URL string that is part of a web query and cannot get the value to change. Here is the code:

```
Dim FC_Name As String
FC_Name = Worksheets("Home").Range("H4")



Sheets("PickWorkforce").Visible = True
Sheets("PickWorkforce").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.ClearContents
    urlStr = "https://picking-nexus.iad.amazon.com/FC_Name/Workforce/data"
With Sheets("PickWorkforce").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & urlStr, Destination:=Sheets("PickWorkforce").Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "employeeRoster?&warehouseId=FC_Name"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
Range("L1") = "Employee Id"
Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11], Roster!R2C2:R10000C13, 12,FALSE),"""") "
Range("L2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L1000"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Sheets("PickWorkforce").Visible = True
End Sub
```

"FC_Name" is the part I am trying to change in the URL, so it reads from whatever warehouse ID I type into a cell of the home page of my workbook.

Can anyone please help me with this ?

Comment: `.Name = "employeeRoster?&warehouseId=FC_Name"` should be  `Name = "employeeRoster?&warehouseId="+FC_Name` I think?

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it returned me the same blank page I have been getting. When I actually put a warhouse ID ex. "urlStr = "https://picking-nexus.iad.amazon.com/PHL7/Workforce/data" . It will give me the appropriate information for that warehouse , but only if I change it in the URL itself

Comment: Oh shoot, I didn't even notice the first FC_Name --- check Jordan's answer

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend removing any `Select` methods from your code and simply refer to the ranges.

When referring to a variable it needs to be outside of quotation marks and concatenated using ampersands (`&`):

```
Dim FC_Name As String

FC_Name = Worksheets("Home").Range("H4")

Sheets("PickWorkforce").Visible = True
Sheets("PickWorkforce").Cells.ClearContents
    urlStr = "https://picking-nexus.iad.amazon.com/" & FC_Name & "/Workforce/data"

With Sheets("PickWorkforce").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;" & urlStr, Destination:=Sheets("PickWorkforce").Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "employeeRoster?&warehouseId=" & FC_Name
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebTables = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8"
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Range("L1") = "Employee Id"
Range("L2").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-11], Roster!R2C2:R10000C13, 12,FALSE),"""") "
Range("L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L1000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Sheets("PickWorkforce").Visible = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Jordan , this worked perfectly! All of my information is now pulling correctly.